# Query optimization with number of tables join and order by with limit clause

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, distinct, limit, resultset

I have a query which has multiple tables joined using distincct - left join - order by - limit clause.

The query looks like this:-

```
Select DISTINCT a.col1, b.col2, c.col3, d.col4, e.col5, f.col6, g.col7, h.col8, 
i.col9, j.col10
From test_a a 
left join test_b b on a.col1 = b.col2 
left join test_c c on c.col1 = d.col2 
left join test_d d on d.col1 = c.col2 
left join test_e e on e.col1 = d.col2 
left join test_f f on f.col1 = e.col2 
left join test_g g on g.col1 = f.col2 
left join test_h h on h.col1 = a.col1 
left join test_i i on i.col1 = f.col2 
left join test_j j on j.col1 = i.col2
Where a.col2 = 'Y' 
and c.col4  = 1
Order by h.col5 desc 
limit 50;
```

All the column used the in coditions has index on it. And explan output of this query gives resultset where I can see it uses all the index properly and total rows it scanned from all the tables is 18000.

What I am wondering in this query is. It runs within seconds if I run it without order by clause. Something like:

```
Select DISTINCT a.col1, b.col2, c.col3, d.col4, e.col5, f.col6, g.col7, h.col8, 
i.col9, j.col10
From test_a a 
left join test_b b on a.col1 = b.col2 
left join test_c c on c.col1 = d.col2 
left join test_d d on d.col1 = c.col2 
left join test_e e on e.col1 = d.col2 
left join test_f f on f.col1 = e.col2 
left join test_g g on g.col1 = f.col2 
left join test_h h on h.col1 = a.col1 
left join test_i i on i.col1 = f.col2 
left join test_j j on j.col1 = i.col2
Where a.col2 = 'Y' 
and c.col4  = 1
limit 50;
```

And if I run it with order by clause then it takes 30-40 seconds to execute.

I tried using the index hint functionality provided by `mysql:- USE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (idx_h_col5)`, but I am getting syntax error while executing this query. The error message says incorrect syntax near

I have one composite index on the column used in order by clause. I also tried creating a single index on this column but nothing really works.

Comment: How many rows do the tables have? It would help if you provided the execution plan for the ordered query. And the tables' structure (PK, FKs) and existing indexes.

Comment: Most of the tables have million plus rows in it. I'll get the ouput of explain and put it here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can use keys for sorting instead of sorting the result after fetching the data, but only if several conditions are met.
You can see a list of these conditions here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

In your case, I think that the multiple JOINs prevent the quick sorting. One of the mentioned cases in which MySQL can't use an index for sorting is:

> You are joining many tables, and the
>   columns in the ORDER BY are not all
>   from the first nonconstant table that
>   is used to retrieve rows. (This is the
>   first table in the EXPLAIN output that
>   does not have a const join type.)

I am not sure if there is a way around it. It depends on the tables structure and the actual query.

To get more help, try posting the explain output of the ordered query.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try adding compound indices on:

```
Table a
    (col2, col1)

Table b
    (col4, col1)
```

and a simple index on

```
Table h
    (col5)
```